Show That For Every Finite Group $G$ and Field $$ - $G$ is Isomorphic to a Sub-Group of $GL(V)$ for Some finite-dimensional Vector Space $V$ over F
I need to show that if a group $G$ is finite, then for every field $$  there's a finite-dimensional vector space $V$ over it such that $G$ is isomorphic to a sub-group of $GL(V)$.
I figured the vector space I should take is $V = ^n$. Then, I tried using the First Isomorphism Theorem in some way, but couldn't find a sub-group of $GL(V)$ that I could create an isometry between $G$ and it.
Am I on the right track? If so, where should I take this idea? If not, what's the right way to tackle and solve this problem? Any ideas will be welcomed!

Use Cayley's theorem.

@QiaochuYuan could you explain how?

Cayley's theorem tells you that $G$ embeds into a symmetric group $S_n$, so the problem reduces to embedding a symmetric group $S_n$ into a general linear group. Now, can you see a linear action of $S_n$ on $F^n$?

I think I got it, thanks!

Think permutation matrices!
